# Vim : youCompleteme plugin opens up a split window with function definition

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I just downloaded and stated using the YCM plugin for vim. However I noticed that whenever the auto-complete pops up giving completion suggestions a split window also opens up in my current window. Any suggestions on how I can configure YCM to not open up a split window ? or at least shut the window when I select something.

Comment: Grep for `:sp` or `sp` or `split` or `:vs` or `:vsplit` in your plugin files. If you find it in any file ,  put those lines here.

Comment: I'll update the post with the find

Comment: This window is called the preview window. See: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_add_preview_to_completeopt-option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your .vimrc file add this line :

`let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1`

According to the documentation :

> When this option is set to 1, YCM will auto-close the preview window after the user leaves insert mode. This option is irrelevant if g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion is set or if no preview window is triggered. See the g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt option for more details.

For more infos : https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion-option

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

I think it fixes that according to
https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/2015